# WinAPI. Открыть изображение через диалоговое окно

Tags: winapi

Использую код с примера для создания диалогового окна:

```
PWSTR  MultiselectInvoke(HWND hwnd)
{


    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED |
        COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        IFileOpenDialog* pFileOpen;

        // Create the FileOpenDialog object.
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL,
            IID_IFileOpenDialog, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pFileOpen));

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Show the Open dialog box.
            hr = pFileOpen->Show(NULL);

            // Get the file name from the dialog box.
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                IShellItem* pItem;
                hr = pFileOpen->GetResult(&pItem);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    PWSTR pszFilePath;
                    hr = pItem->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &pszFilePath);

                    // Display the file name to the user.
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        //MessageBox(NULL, pszFilePath, L"File Path", MB_OK);
                        //CoTaskMemFree(pszFilePath);
                    }
                    pItem->Release();
                }
            }
            pFileOpen->Release();
        }
        CoUninitialize();
    }
    return pszFilePath;
}
```

Функция возвращает путь к файлу. дальше пытаюсь его подставить в функцию LoadImage():

```
hDC = GetDC(hWND);
            CompatibleDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
            SelectObject(CompatibleDC, hPen);
            HANDLE HndBitmap;
            HndBitmap = LoadImage(NULL,path, IMAGE_BITMAP, 905, 677, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
            GetObject(HndBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &Bitmap);
            SelectObject(CompatibleDC, HndBitmap);
            StretchBlt(hDC, 0, 0, 1000, 800, CompatibleDC, 0, 0, Bitmap.bmWidth, Bitmap.bmHeight, SRCCOPY);
```

Но ничего не происходит, изображение не появляется, только если прописать путь в ручном режиме типа "D:\img.bmp". Есть еще соображения - окно загрузки файлов возвращает путь в виде D:\, тогда как он вроде прописывается с двумя косыми чертами \, может в этом проблема? Или нужно провести какие то операции выхода из папки приложения (типа //..//), и только потом вводить полный путь? вида  D:\img.bmp?

Comment: Если у вас при задании строки вручную работает, а при задании строки из `path` не работает, значит в `path` содержится мусор вместо пути к файлу (элементарно, Ватсон, чудес не бывает). Перед вызовом `GetDC` поставьте `MessageBox` да посмотрите что там лежит. А так по вашему кусочку кода не понять что вы там сделали и что вы в `path` кладете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, изначально функция `MultiselectInvoke` позволяла пользователю выбрать группу файлов и вероятно, распечатать их имена. Затем кто-то ее переработал как умел - она по-прежнему выбирает группу файлов, но отдает наружу только одно имя.

Но самое главное, что она отдает наружу не полный путь, а дружественное имя файла, которое далеко не всегда совпадает с реальным именем, и уж точно не содержит путь к файлу. Неудивительно, что по этому имени программа никакого файла не находит.

В общем, выкиньте этот шедевр, лучше попробуйте что-нибудь попроще. Например,

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

BOOL GetFileName(LPTSTR nameBuffer) {
    *nameBuffer = _T('\0');
    OPENFILENAME ofn;
    memset(&ofn, 0, sizeof(ofn));
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.lpstrTitle = _TEXT("Dialog Title");
    ofn.lpstrFilter = _TEXT("All Files (*.*)\0*.*\0");
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
    ofn.lpstrInitialDir = _TEXT("C:\\");
    ofn.lpstrFile = nameBuffer;
    ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_NONETWORKBUTTON | OFN_HIDEREADONLY;
    return ::GetOpenFileName(&ofn);
}
```

Возвращает `TRUE` если успешно и `FALSE` если юзер нажал Cancel. Вызывается так:

```
TCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
BOOL res = GetFileName(path);
if (!res) {
    Юзер не хочет - надо выйти из программы или еще что-то сделать
}
```

Comment: Работает! Огромное Спасибо!